# How to use Gson to convert simple object to string?

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, gson

This is the JSON I received.

```
data:[
    ...
    casts:[
        {
            name:"Jack"
        },
        {
            name:"Mary"
        },
        {
            name:"Jane"
        },
    ],
    ...
]
```

Of course, it need to accept the JSON by javaBean like:

```
data class Movie(
    ...
    val casts:List<Cast>,
    ...
)
```

But the `Cast` class is a simple String so I want to accept the JSON by

```
data class Movie(
    ...
    val casts:List<String>,
    ...
)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You can't replace it with a simple string. The structure of your object is `{name: <value>}` so you need a type to match that structure. `[{name: "Jack"}]` is different from `["Jack"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have in your json is a `List<Cast>`, and the `Cast` class is a simple `String` so what you could do is get the list of `Cast` and then get the `list[index].name` to get the `String`

In case you'd like a `List<String>` you should have this as `json`

```
[
  "Jhon",
  "Anne",
  "Carl"
]
```

Then you'd be able to do this :

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
val list = gson.fromJson<ArrayList<String>>(stringObject, object :TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>(){}.type)
```